# Update the order items in in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I have an ordering app which have order items. I was able to update the field which only have single data but I can't make the field that handle an array data work. The order items belongs to another model called OrderItems. Can you help on to deal with this properly?

here's my update function.

```
public function update(Request $request, Orders $order )
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'status_id' => 'required',
            'currency_id' => 'required',
            'company_id' => 'required',
            'purchase_no' => 'required|unique:orders,purchase_no,'.$order->id,
            'notes' => '',
            'admin_notes' => '',
            'delivery_date' => '',
            'publish' => '',
            'product_id' => 'required',
            'product_code' => 'required',
            'product_name' => 'required',
            'quantity' => 'required'
        ]);

        $order->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
        $order->status_id= $request->input('status_id');
        $order->currency_id = $request->input('currency_id');
        $order->company_id = $request->input('company_id');
        $order->purchase_no = $request->input('purchase_no');
        $order->notes = $request->input('notes');
        $order->admin_notes = $request->input('admin_notes');
        $order->delivery_date = $request->input('delivery_date');
        $order->publish = $request->input('publish');
        $order->grandtotal =  (float) str_replace(',', '', $request->input('grandtotal'));
        $order->save();

        $input = Orderitems::findOrFail($order->id);
        for($i=0; $i<= count($input['quantity']); $i++) {
        if(empty($input['quantity'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['quantity'][$i])) continue;
            $items->product_id = $input->input('product_id')[$i];
            $items->product_code = $input->input('product_code')[$i];
            $items->product_name = $input->input('product_name')[$i];
            $items->cost = $input->input('cost')[$i];
            $items->quantity = $input->input('quantity')[$i];
            $items->total_cost = (float) str_replace(',', '', $input->input('total_cost')[$i]);
            $orderItems->save();
        }
        return redirect()->route('orders.index');
    }
```

Here's the screenshot from my update form
[image]

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written wrong code for the update.it should be like this.

You are saving `$orderItems`object which hasn't updated in your code.

```
$items= $order->orderItems;

// still code not updated here i want to print product _id ?
foreach($items as $key => $item) {

$item->product_id = $request->input('product_id')[$key];
$item->product_code = $request->input('product_code')[$key];
$item->product_name = $request->input('product_name')[$key];
$item->cost = $request->input('cost')[$key];
$item->quantity = $request->input('quantity')[$key];
$item->total_cost = (float) str_replace(',', '', $request->input('total_cost')[$key]);
$item->save();
}
```

Comment: Hi @jigarHalani. Thanks for responding. still doesn't work. I also change the $input inside the "for" and "if"

Comment: one order have many orderitems so in that case can you check $items is array or single object ?

Comment: if its array then you need to loop throgh array and update each item

Comment: it says " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';' "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189505/discussion-between-jigar-halani-and-lito-lozada).